# How to select one entry from duplicates?

Tags: c#

how to be, for example, if there are 80 records that you need (but 30 of them are repeated)
But it is necessary to output one of these repeating one field at a time (only one field will always be repeated) without losing the sequence of data?

These are the records in the database that need to be displayed on the UI and the sequence should not change (roughly speaking, we display the records in the database as well)

```
        var result = rpcResponse.Result;
        var resultRepeating = result.Where(x => x.Event == Event.SendEmail).FirstOrDefault();
```

So, my problem is that there is an Event field which is Enum. But I have to display one and only one of the some type of this enum.

Is it possible to extract just one repeating record for specifit enum value?

Comment: Do you have any preferences about what record of all duplicates you want to return, the latest?

Comment: @TimSchmelter in best scenarious - latest.

Comment: according to what property?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of LINQ and grouping:

```
var result = rpcResponse.Result;

var uniqueRecords = result.GroupBy(x => x.Event)
                          .Select(group => group.FirstOrDefault())
                          .ToList();
```

Comment: `FirstOrDefault` is not necessary. Better to use `First`, because every available event-group has at least one record, otherwise the `GroupBy` would not have returned it.

Comment: Event(property)=> Enum, big enough. Each of them means some kind of event.
I just need to select from this Enum only ONE with 52 by value from the list.